# How to print SVM model progress log in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, svm

I've trained a SVM model using statement as following, in Jupyter notebook.

```
  svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train.drop(X_train.columns[[1,2,3]],axis=1), y_train)
```

Due to large data size, it takes some time to complete. Is there any log from SVM? if yes, is there a way to show SVM running log in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that this is scikit-learn

Most models have a `verbose` parameter that when fitting will give some insight into the process of fitting the model.

So, run:

```
svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, verbose=True).fit(X_train.drop(X_train.columns[[1,2,3]],axis=1), y_train)
```

Comment: after adding verbose=True,  I did see the log in the terminal screen instead of notebook browser. On the browser, I can only one line print out as `[LibSVM]` in notebook.  Is there any extra congiguration required to view log details?

Comment: @HappyCoding I have same problem, any news ?